# Showcase website that will reinstall itself every day?

Tags: magento, cron, cron-task

I have built a showcase Magento installation that I am about to deploy public. I'd like to give people backend access but indeed I don't want their changes to stick - not sure how to go about this. What's the best way?

I have seen a Magento showcase somewhere that gave the backend access stating the website will be renewed every 12 hours. So I suppose there is a cron job starting a script that will copy contents of one directory into the other (the public one)  every 12 hours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two good solutions:

### 1. Virtual Machine

Run the entire site in a virtual machine or VPS. Make a snapshot of the machine when it is in the state you want to reset it to. Have a cronjob that triggers the "return to snapshot" routine. The exact details vary between hosts but look for a host with an API.

### 2. File Copy and DB Reset

Keep a copy of all the files in another folder, together with a dump of the database. You can use [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html) to create a database dump. You can then go back to that state by having a cronjob that removes the current folder, copies back the old folder and imports the database dump.

There are a few ways to [import the database dump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-batch-commands.html) file, including the SOURCE command:

```
SOURCE dumpfile.sql;
```

Comment: Brilliant. Also thanks for mentioning the SOURCE command, I'd have hard time looking this up.